# executable jar console, where are my println()?

Tags: java, windows, console, executable-jar

I implemented an application that can 'works' in GUI mode or in console mode. That means if the user ( in a windows console cmd) launchs the application without parameter
`\>myapplication.jar`
 the GUI start. If the user starts the application and gives some parameters, like
`\>myapplication.jar -src sourcefile`
, the gui isn't started but the prg interprets the arguments. Now my problem, if a run the application with the prefix 
`\>java -jar myapplication.jar -somethings`
 I see all ***system.out.println()*** in the console, it's fine. If I start the application 
`\>myapplication.jar -somethings` 
, all my ***system.out.println(..)*** aren't displayed ?? in the console. Why ?

Somebody has a solution to avoid to type each time the prefix ***>java -jar***. I don't want to use a script like 'bash file' before. 
Thanks in advance, Alex

(some precisions, the system is windows 7 and I don't have the admin right on this pc)

Comment: It is quite unclear what the problem is, can you post the minimal code to reproduce your problem? Or at least show how you handle arguments and your print command.

Comment: Hello user3779430, I exported to an executable jar (Eclipse). If I type in an open console <code>myapplication.jar</code> gui is started, it's ok. If I type the same command but with arguments, the gui isn't started, its correct, the application interprets the arguments, but I don't see my system.out in the console. In gui mode all information are displayed in the GUI, in console mode, I would like to see the information in the console. It's work if I start the application with the command <code>java -jar myapplication.jar</code>

Comment: you should edit your question and add the code rather than adding it into a new comment, so that everyone can see it at first sight :)

Answer (score 0):

`java -jar ...` tells the commandline to run `java` with the specified arguments in the open console. `somejar.jar -arg` tells windows to open somejar.jar with the given argument. but this will create a completely new process that does **not** use the console in which you typed the command. So 'somejar.jar' is printing, but not to a visible console.

Comment: Hello Paul, thx, ok I understand. Now, it's possible to redirect the output from this new process to this active console ?

Comment: nope, separated memory. even if it was possible, it would be a lot easier to simply type `java -jar`